# C++ memcpy и сохранность ссылок и прочего

Tags: c++, безопасность, vector, копирование

Всем привет! У меня несколько абстрактный вопрос: Я делаю собственный вектор и насмотревшись гадов по его созданию задался вопросом, а почему все так боятся использовать memcpy? И realloc тоже? Это же удобные функции для того,чтобы не вызывать ненужные конструкторы, ведь объекты же не меняются по факту,так как вектор лишь увеличивается при добавлении элемента. Но все упорно используют кривые циклы с приравнивание или вообще new/delete которые вызывают деструктор в и конструкторы, хотя ты только хотел добавлять вектор.

P.S. вообще почему векторы не делать на malloc и free? Тогда никаких вызовов деструкторов и конструкторов без необходимости.

Answer (score 5):

Представьте класс, который сохраняет свой адрес в какую-то глобальную переменную (мапу?). В своих копирующих (если они не удалены) и перемещающих операциях он бы обновлял этот глобальный объект. А вы, используя `memcpy` вместо правильных конструкторов и операторов присваивания, сломали бы эту логику.

Стандарт запрещает использовать `memcpy`на классах с не[тривиальными](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Trivially_copyable_class) копирующими или перемещающими операциями (т. е. такими, которые не просто копируют байты).

> все упорно используют кривые циклы

Это единственный легальный способ.

> не вызывать ненужные конструкторы

Если они и правда ненужные, то по хорошему компилятор должен сам их выбросить (если их почему-то не спрятали из хедера в .cpp-шник).

> почему векторы не делать на malloc и free?

Только на них и можно (или на `operator new()` и `operator delete()`, которые ведут себя так же), потому что `new` и `delete` не позволят зарезервировать память, не создавая сразу в ней объекты.

Объекты в этой памяти нужно создавать самому, с помощью placement-new и ручного вызова деструкторов; надеюсь, понятно почему.

Comment: Т.е. если нетривиальный конструктор копирования, то можно только с помощью цикла присваивания? Но тогда это будет заметно медленнее,если объектов много или они большие?

Comment: А можно как-то в шаблоне вектора сделать проверку на наличие нетривиального копирования? Чтобы создавалось 2 вектора, один для простых, а другой для тривиальных.

Comment: @SupremeMachine *"проверку на наличие нетривиального копирования"* Не поверите, `std::is_trivially_copyable`. Но, еще раз, попробуйте циклом и посмотрите на результат со включённой оптимизацией - должно получиться то же самое.

Comment: внезапно я вернулся к старому вопросу) А точнее хотелось бы узнать, нужно ли при цикле копирования инициализировать конструктором (ну с помощью placement new) сырую память, в которую копируется уже нормальный новый объект(с нетривиальным конструктором копирования)?
И как быть, если нет тривиального конструктора(обычного)? Тогда placement new(или даже обычный new[]) не сработают?

Comment: @SupremeMachine Конечно placement-new нужен. А что вы вместо него хотели позвать? *''как быть, если нет тривиального конструктора(обычного)"* Вот это не понял. Во-первых, "обычный" - это какой? Во-вторых, какая разница, тривиальный или нет? Нужен только копирующий конструктор, не важно, тривиальный или нет.

Comment: Ну допустим я выделил память с помощью new() или malloc() под новые элементы. Она сырая. А потом вставляю в нее какой-то объект, у которого есть нетривиальное копирование. Нужно ли перед самим копированием вызвать placement new на ту ячейку, куда будет вставлен(скопирован) новый объект?

Comment: @SupremeMachine *"перед самим копированием"* Что есть копирование? Вообще, там нужен только вызов копирующего констурктора через placement-new.